# QSignalMapper does not trigger SLOT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use `QSignalMapper` with my buttons, but I can't seem to get it to work to trigger my slot.

Here is my code for the SignalMapper:

In my header:

```
...
private:

    QSignalMapper *mapper;
```

In my cpp:

```
//Constructor:
mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

//Init function, called by the constructor
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(HandleSignalEvents(int)));
```

Here is the code for connecting my button to it:

```
connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(m_ui->addEntryButton, 1);
```

Both connects are returning `true` as value, so the connects should be setup correctly. However, this slot is not being triggered at all:

```
public slots:

    void HandleSignalEvents(int);

----------------------------------------

void UIController::HandleSignalEvents(int param)
{
    //Do something    
}
```

I get no error whatsoever, so I can't really figure out what the problem ist. Both connects seem to work as usual, but the action does not trigger.

What could possibly go wrong here?

EDIT:

Note that `m_signalMapper` is a private member value of the class.

EDIT2:

Due to demand, here is my whole constructor chain:

```
UIController::UIController(Ui::TodoListerClass &ui)
{
    //Unrelated initializations
    mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    Init();
}

void UIController::Init()
{
    connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(HandleSignalEvents(int)));

    InitUI();
    InitBinds();
}

void UIController::InitBinds()
{
    connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
    mapper->setMapping(m_ui->addEntryButton, 1);
}
```

Edit 2:

More code:

Main:

```
#include "todolister.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TodoLister w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

TodoLister(.h):

```
class TodoLister : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TodoLister(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TodoLister();

private: 
    Ui::TodoListerClass ui;
};
```

TodoLister(.cpp):

```
TodoLister::TodoLister(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    UIController uiController(ui);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will make a difference, but is there a special reason why you use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `QSharedPointer`? To keep things simple you can even make your `QSignalMapper` instance a member object, or pass an instance of a `QObject` as parent if you really need to make instantiate it on the heap. And just to be sure, does it work if you create the mapper as member variable on the stack instead of using the heap? Is there any console output? (As slots use late binding problems are usually detected and announced at runtime.)

Comment: @Murphy I tried to use a normal QSignalMapper* as well now - as a member variable - as stated in the Qt tutorial, but it doesn't seem to change anything. There is also no output at all.

Comment: @Sossenbinder did you set the parent of the QSignalMapper ?

Comment: @Sossenbinder could you edit to the updated code ...?

Comment: You have to drop the `std::shared_ptr<QSignalMapper>` though.

Comment: @Ilya yeah, I decided to switch to a vanilla pointer for now as well until I find out how to fix it.

Comment: @Sossenbinder why "for now" ? A vanilla pointer is perfectly OK for this case, the lifespan will be managed by the parent.

Comment: @Ilya okay then, I'm just really used to smart pointers so far, as everyone always thaught me how safe they were. I still can't get the main problem to work, though.

Comment: @Sossenbinder you don't need smart pointer for anything widgets-related (and most things really) in Qt because the parent-child relationship takes care of ownership and lifetime without hassle. And mixing with smart pointers can break the code if misused. NB there's still a `get` in the code you've posted.

Comment: @Sossenbinder there's no obvious problem in your code now, could you provide the full constructor maybe ?

Comment: @Ilya I added the constructor chain for you

Comment: @Sossenbinder could you also show the instantiation of `UIController` ?

Comment: @Ilya Alright, I guess that's all I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TodoLister::TodoLister(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    UIController uiController(ui);
}
```

Your `uiController` object goes out of scope when the constructor returns, so can't emit signals afterwards because it is deleted.

Comment: Hooray, that worked, finally! I didn't even expect the error to be there, but now it works. Thanks alot for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You are defining the shared pointer in the stack, not in the heap, so if you probably declared it in the constructor, the variable will get deleted when it finishes, not being accesible through out the rest of the program. Define it as a private variable of the class.

**OLD**
In the documentation of QSignalMapper, the example of connect is at follows:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
```

whilst you have signalMapper.get().  That parameter corresponds to the OBJECT receiving the signal, not a method of the object, so you should try `signalMapper` alone.

The same applies to the first connect, where you have specified the OBJECT generating the signal as `signalMapper.get()`, instead of `signalMapper`

Comment: Yes, thats true, but compared the the doc I am using a smart pointer, so the .get() would only return the raw pointer needed as an argument

Comment: @Sossenbinder don't use smart pointers, use parent-child relationships - that's simpler.

Comment: Ok, true @Sossenbinder, didn't see that. Maybe it is because you are declaring the shared pointer in the stack (and I guess in the constructor), so when the constructor finishes, it deletes the smart pointer. Try declaring the smart pointer as a private variable of the class, in that way the object will persist throughout the whole life of the class.

Comment: @GabrielRequenaGarcía That's the way I am doing it right now, I just compressed it a bit so it fits better in the post.

Comment: @Ilya What do you mean with that?

Comment: @Sossenbinder I mean `new QSignalMapper(this)`, `this` will manage the deleting of the object, no need of a smart pointer.

Comment: @Sossenbinder but are you implementing it just as you have posted it? Coz if that is the case, you are redeclaring the variable by putting the type before the definition, so it'll mask the private variable.

Comment: @Sossenbinder if it is a private member, just put `this->m_signalMapper = std::shared_ptr<QSignalMapper>(new QSignalMapper(this));`